# Using Video as Environment uses only first frame on renders

Tags: animation, eevee-render-engine, lighting, video, hdri

Complete blender beginner here, so maybe I'm overlooking something.

To light my object I've created an Environment Texture Node. I've set it to "movie" and loaded a video file. When I scroll through the timeline every frame in the shaded preview looks like it uses a different frame from the video, but when I render an animation sequence, it uses only one frame of the video for all the rendered frames.

Tried using "auto refresh" both on and off. Also tried using image sequence. Same results.

I'm using Blender 3.0 with EEVEE on MacOS 11.6.

Comment: pls provide blend file

Comment: Here's the link to the files: https://disk.yandex.com/d/KsR4wVGZgeUgCQ

Answer (score 1):

So I've been dealing with this exact issue, animated image sequence used as an HDRI In eevee and it works and looks fine in viewport. Yet anytime I rendered the animation, the HDRI would stay as whatever first frame I started the render from and not cycle through its frames.

I accidentally found a solution, go into the world tab and add a keyframe in the viewport display color property. Any frame. Just add a keyframe. For some reason, this solves it for me and suddenly my HDRI is animated in render.

[image]

Comment: If that is easy to replicate and still causes the same problem at the latest Blender release, you should report it as a bug.

Answer (score 0):

You've set it in the World background or where? Have you set the number of frames in the *Environment Texture*? If you import an image sequence, the frames are automatically set to the number of images you've imported, but when you use a movie it sets the frames by default to 1 (maybe because the movie is just one file), it's not using all the frames of the movie by default.

Using an *Image Sequence*:

[image: image sequence]

Using a *Movie*:

[image: movie]

But if that would be the solution I'm curious why it shows correctly in the viewport.

Comment: Exactly, I've set it in the World background. At first I just set the Environment Texture node without preceding Texture Coordinate/Mapping nodes as in your example. I then tried to follow your example. And of course I had the number of frames set to the number of frames in the video.

The strange behaviour is exactly the point that it is shown correctly when scrolling through the timeline in the viewport...

Comment: Now I changed the rendering engine to cycles and it works. (The renders don't look even nearly as good though.) So it must be some incompatibility issue/bug?

Comment: @mrdenim The _Texture Coordinate_ in my screenshot wasn't intended for the answer, this was just in my setup needed to show a certain part in the camera view. However, my problem with this in Eevee is, the movie plays without any problem - so I'm wondering what your problem is. Using only one frame sounds exactly like what I described here. My problem in Eevee is that the movie lights the scene in viewport, but not in render. But the renders in Cycles don't look as good as in Eevee? Why? But maybe you should really upload the file to check out why it plays only one frame.

Comment: I have compressed the video for the upload, but the results are still the same. In the preview everything works fine, but the rendering just uses one frame... Here's the link: https://disk.yandex.com/d/KsR4wVGZgeUgCQ